# Select specific column in an inner join SQL statement

Tags: sql, inner-join

I want to select a specific column (`Name`) from `Products` on the last inner join I have. How can I do that?

This is my SQL statement:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM CustomerDetails cd INNER JOIN CustomerProducts cp ON cp.CustomerID = cd.Id INNER JOIN Products p ON cp.ProductID = p.ProductID", conn);
```

So far I got this, is it possible to have one column for this? Like `Name` has carbon dioxide, industrial oxygen since they are in the same Id? Thank you

[image]

Comment: `select p.name from Customer Details ...`

Comment: It is possible that `name` is a reserved word. Please update your question with the RDBMS you're using and we can provide appropriate information on how to handle that.

Comment: in your select use the table alias of the table you need like select p.columnname

Comment: thank you @bernie but i still need the * on customer details

Comment: Ok then do `select p.name, cd.* from Customer Details ...`

Comment: Never use select * in production code. That is a SQL antipattern, simply pick out the columns you need.

Comment: As per your edit, do you mean you want one row for customer details, and carbon dioxide and industrial oxygen as additional columns?

Comment: if possible i want it to be as one column as name. so under column name it will be `carbon dioxide and industrial oxygen` since they are both Id number 10

Comment: any idea sir @Simon, should i add a where function? thank you

Comment: I updated my answer to include a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select p.[name], cd.* FROM CustomerDetails cd Inner Join CustomerProducts cp ON cp.CustomerID = cd.Id Inner Join Products p ON cp.ProductID = p.ProductID", conn);
```

EDIT: I agree with the comment below, cd.* is not advised, it should be cd.Id, cd.CustomerName... etc.

This should get you the names grouped together in a single column:

```
;WITH Customers AS
(
    select cd.Id, cd.customer ... FROM CustomerDetails cd 
)

SELECT stuff(
(
    select ', ' + p.[name] FROM Customers cd Inner Join CustomerProducts cp ON cp.CustomerID = cd.Id Inner Join Products p ON cp.ProductID = p.ProductID
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 2, '')
, c.Id, c.CustomerName ...
FROM Customers c
```

Comment: While this works, it is a SQL antipattern. The OP should actually define the columns he wants.

Comment: worked for me. last question sir please see update please

Comment: wil try it out sir

Comment: is this for a stored procedure sir?

Answer (score -1):

```
select p.Name, cd.ColumnA, cd.ColumnB, cd.ColumnC
FROM CustomerDetails cd 
Inner Join CustomerProducts cp ON cp.CustomerID = cd.Id 
Inner Join Products p ON cp.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

Comment: i still need the columns from customer details sir